# How did people ensure that renaissance Papal election bribery was honored?

Tags: catholic-church, papacy

Some papal elections during the rennaisance were notorious for allegations of bribery. For example the [1492 conclave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_conclave,_1492) which elected Rodrigo Borgia as Pope Alexander VI. The amount needed for bribes were considerable, e.g. Wikipedia mentioned "four mule-loads of silver". Also, elections were not frequent enough for people to simply trust each other by habit. How did people ensure that such a risky transaction was honored?

If the payment was first, how could the payer know that, after that big payment, the cardinal would vote as requested? If the payment was later, how could the cardinal know that he would be paid?

Comment: a third party maybe?

Comment: To begin with, those interested in Papal elections and with the means to bribe cardinals are usually in the rank of Kings and above. It is never wise to cross a King or an Emperor. But, as you comment, there were not enough elections to develop an habit, so probably there was no standard way or price for votes.

Comment: @ed.hank Yeah, like escrow.

Comment: @ed.hank do you have any references to instances of papal election bribery going through a third party?

Comment: Oh no, no source, it was just a guess as to how i would do it.

Comment: Might be on-topic here: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Presumably, part of the bribe was paid in advance and the rest was contingent upon some verification of the result.

Comment: You could ask the same question about any bribe during any period of history, couldn't you?  Should tell you something about bribery, in general.

Comment: I don't know, but I would offer the following hypothesis for testing.  (1) collect as many votes as you can (2) offer bribes to enough people to get your candidate over the top.  If your candidate is elected, assume that all the electors were bought and paid for. If your candidate is not elected, assume that all the electors were faithless and punish them vigorously.    (4) If your candidate is not elected, default on any remaining bribe payments.

Comment: Or just 'if you're full of it and I don't get elected, I'll kill you, are you sure you want to take my money?' I'm afraid the OP is overthinking this a lot!

Answer (score 4):

My guess is, just like today, there was plenty of fraud, people claiming to have the ability to sell votes or offices and not really being able to deliver.

But regarding how such enforcement could have worked, Cardinals often came from families like the [Orsini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orsini_family), [Sforza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Sforza), or [Medici](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Medici) who had very substantial power (military, financial, or via popular support) around Rome and were able to bring some force to bear if they needed to (I believe the power balance between these and other families affected many elections, at least implicitly). Cardinals from other places, such as France, might have the backing of the nobility there who could help enforce any agreements made.

I will also say that buying a papacy might take "four-mule loads of silver" but starting a rumor costs nothing, and if it makes for salacious reading people will spread it for fun. If you don't like Alexander VI or his family, and he isn't around to do anything about it, you can say whatever you want. Alexander VI [sheltered large numbers of Jews exiled](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Catholic_Encyclopedia_(1913)/Pope_Alexander_VI) from Spain, Portugal, and Provence. That would have ruffled a few Roman feathers in those days, but today we would look at that differently (I hope).

Answer (score -2):

Probably the same way that bribery in the elections of bishops was honored?  Or in the elections for MPs from rotten boroughs in England?  What about ensuring that bribery in the elections of municipal officials was honored?  What about elections for king of the Polish-Lithuanian Commonwealth from 1572 to 1796?  What about imperial elections?

There were many elective offices in that era, and in some cases the number of electors, such as the cardinals and the imperial electors, was small enough that bribery was feasible.

So researching allegations of bribery in elections for other offices will no doubt give some clues about the practical mechanics of bribery in papal elections.

Comment: Sorry, too broad to be useful, and perhaps even misleading. Alas, -1.

Comment: For example: in rotten boroughs there were non-secret elections, unlike in the OP's case of interest.